# How to remove duplicates and display only item per userid using PHP?

Tags: php

When I do

```
foreach($hugeobject as $k => $obj){
  echo $obj->userid . " = " . $obj->itemid."<br/>";
}
```

Here's the result:

```
147099 = 594088
147099 = 594086
147099 = 594085
147099 = 594082
147099 = 594083
147099 = 594089
161676 = 594091
196351 = 593971
196351 = 593904
196387 = 593894
196382 = 593892
196382 = 593891
196382 = 593889
196382 = 593888
196351 = 593887
196351 = 593865
196351 = 593864
196722 = 593798
196351 = 593795
196351 = 593794
196351 = 593793
196351 = 593792
196722 = 593790
196351 = 593789
```

And the objective is to display these only:

```
147099 = 594088
161676 = 594091
196351 = 593971
196382 = 593892
196722 = 593798
```

I tried using `array_unique()` and even combined it with `array_map()` and `serialize()`... But neither helped. So how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Please share in what kind of object these are stored. Are these strings including the `=`?

Comment: it's a huge object array where by it has lots of data in it, that data i pasted is only the userid and it's itemid that belongs to it..the "=" is not included..i only showed it that way to make it easy to look at when asking a question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to write this with common `foreach`-loop:

```
<?php

$buffer = array();

foreach($hugeobject as $obj){
    if(isset($buffer[$obj->userid]))continue;

    $buffer[$obj->userid] = $obj;
}

foreach($buffer as $obj){
    echo $obj->userid . " = " . $obj->itemid . "<br/>";
}

?>
```

Comment: please don't include the "=" in your suggested solution...i only put that in my sample data to make my question clearer

Comment: @sasori post the original structure then.

Comment: i posted the loop from where the data came from

Comment: `196351 = 593789
196351 = 593789
196351 = 593789
196351 = 593789
196351 = 593789
196351 = 593789`

Comment: it didn't get the expected objective result

Answer (score -1):

If your data is in an array, then try this:

```
$result = array();
foreach($hugeobject as $k => $obj){
    if(!isset($result[$obj->userid])){
        $result[$obj->userid] = $obj->itemid;
    }
}
```

Comment: This just finds the unique keys, but keys are guaranteed to be unique to begin with. What's the point?